# jQuery mCustomScrollbar update error

Tags: javascript

Here is the problem: I'm using mCustomScrollbar with a div on which data are dinnamicaly loaded from another html file.

Javascript:

```
function updateScrollbar()
{
    $("#frame_holder").mCustomScrollbar('update');
}

function loader(name)
{
    //loads the selected file into div.

    var loading = "./rosliny/"+name+".html";
    $("#frame_holder").load(loading, function () 
    { 
        //enable scrollbar
        $("#frame_holder").mCustomScrollbar();
    }); 
}
```

index.html file:

```
<div id="frame_holder" class="frame_holder"> </div>
<div id="menu_rosliny"><h1>Roślinność</h1>
    <p style="font-family:segoe_ui; font-size:13px; color:white;"> Ogólna charakterystyka</p>
    <p><h1>Drzewa</h1></p>
    <ol style=" cursor:pointer; font-size:13px; color:white; font-family:segoe_ui; text-align:left; paddin:0px; margin:10px; position:relative; top:-10px;">
        <li onclick="loader('brzoza');updateScrollbar();">Brzoza</li>
        <li onclick="loader('buk');updateScrollbar();">Buk</li>
        <li onclick="loader('daglezja');updateScrollbar();">Daglezja</li>
        <li onclick="loader('dab');updateScrollbar();">Dąb</li>
        <li onclick="loader('jodla');updateScrollbar();">Jodła</li>
        <li onclick="loader('klon');updateScrollbar();">Klon</li>
        <li onclick="loader('lipa');updateScrollbar();">Lipa</li>
        <li onclick="loader('modrzew');updateScrollbar();">Modrzew</li>
        <li onclick="loader('sosna');updateScrollbar();">Sosna</li>
        <li onclick="loader('swierk');updateScrollbar();">Świerk</li>
        <li onclick="loader('wiaz');updateScrollbar();">Wiąz</li>
    </ol>
```

Html site to load:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h2>Modrzew europejski <em>(Larix decidua Mill.)</em></h2>
        <p class="rosliny_opis"></p>
        <h2>Ciekawostki</h2>
        <p class="rosliny_opis"></p>
        <p class="rosliny_opis"></p>
        <img id="obr_rosl" src="./images/rosliny/modrzew.png"/>
        <!-- end .content -->
    </div>
  <!-- end .container -->
</div> <br/>
```

When I click on li element a webpage containging text and image should be loaded into #frame_holder div. This works correctly. But after that scrollbar update should occur. That is not happen. I can only click once again on the same li element and then the mCustomScrollbar recalculates and works ok. **What should I do to make this code work properly after the first click?** Please help me, because I'm run out of ideas.

Comment: Here is the website: [link](www.remeda.pl/test2/index.html) When you click "Rośliny" button you will see a div with two divs inside. The left one is the menu and the right is #frame_holder. I hope that will help you to understand my problem.

Comment: I dont see any issue on your given link. When you click on "Roślinność" text at bottom of page, modal appears.

Comment: @shekhardesigner Try to click on menu elements which appear. For example when you click "Modrzew" on the first list the scrollbar will not apear and the image is cut. After second click everything is ok. And I want to get rid of this problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be issue with multiple calls of `mCustomScrollbar()` after each loader without destroying it and again calling the update.

Ideally you should call `mCustomScrollbar()` once after you show the modal, means when you click on **Roślinność** at bottom of page. Loader function fall back should have then update method then.

First get rid of this function: `updateScrollbar();`

Second, call this after **Roślinność** click: `$("#frame_holder").mCustomScrollbar();`

Third, update scrollbar inside loader function:
**Edit:** load inside the frame_holder's generated container (`.mCSB_container`).

```
function loader(name)
{
    //loads the selected file into div.

    var loading = "./rosliny/"+name+".html";
    $("#frame_holder .mCSB_container").load(loading, function () 
    { 
        //enable scrollbar
        $("#frame_holder").mCustomScrollbar('update');
    }); 
}
```

Comment: @shekardesigner I've done everything you said:
1. removed all calls of updateScrollbar();
2. added to roslinnosc click the code which trigger the custom scrollbar
3. put the 'update' line into loader function.

 But now the mCustomScrollbar dissapear. I see only the standard scrollbar generated by browser. What the hell is going on? ;)

Comment: @shekardesigner Maybe this issue is connected to image loading speed? Maybe the mScrollbar do not see the image, because it is loading, and do not calculate the div height properly? I think that on the second click image is taken from browser cache and mScrollBar catches it. But I do not know how to resolve it...

Comment: Once the `mCustomScrollbar` method is called, your frame_holder div structure changes, hence again calling .load() for the same messes the generated scrollbar. I have modified the answer (updated the loader method), plz check once.

Comment: @shekardesigner Thanks a lot :-) that worked for me :-D i have also found another way- ive set the demand height of images in css. So this two methods work :-) but yours is more proffesional :-)